# Настройка среды IDLE: как запустить пошаговое выполнение (debugger)

Tags: python, отладка, idle

Как запустить пошагово код в IDLE, либо выделенный фрагмент кода?

Например у меня есть рекрутивная функция, я не могу сообразить как она работает, поэтому хочу запустить пошаговую трассировку, чтобы видеть какой шаг когда выполняется, как это можно реализовать в стандартной среде питона IDLE

Comment: Добавьте больше описания к Вашей проблеме.

Comment: Например у меня есть рекрутивная функция, я не могу сообразить как она работает, поэтому хочу запустить пошаговую трассировку, чтобы видеть какой шаг когда выполняется, как это можно реализовать в стандартной среде питона IDLE

Comment: прикрепите это к своему вопросу. Нажмите "править" и добавьте этот текст.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, в стандартном IDLE нет возможности запускать код пошагово.

Вы можете воспользоваться сторонним сервисом, например
http://pythontutor.ru/visualizer/

Comment: 1- не стандартный IDLE мне неизвестен :) 2- [документация говорит](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html), что есть debugger  3- Хотя для разработки, IDLE (вне учебного  класса) обычно (когда есть возможность ПО ставить) не используют. Вот что создатель языка сказал: [*"Don't waste time improving IDLE, the process is too slow / broken. Building something new will be quicke and much better."*](https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/624134950283907072) Сейчас куча опций доступна для разных потребностей.

Comment: Да как раз про debugger я и спрашивал, не могу с ним разобраться, но всё равно спасибо

Comment: @ОлегФантанский если вы откроете debugger (должны увидеть: `[DEBUG ON]`) и  ваш скрипт по F5 или прямо в REPL код запустите, то нажимая на кнопки Step, Over в debugger вы можете вперёд по шагам двигаться.

Answer (score 1):

Импортируете в свой модуль [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pdb.html)

```py
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

pdb - стандартный модуль отладки для python включенный в состав интерпретатора. Он будет отображаться в окне IDLE Debugger.

Comment: ИМХО: По мере роста потребностей взгляните на PyCharm Comminity Edition - это бесплатная IDE для Python с очень хорошим отладчиком.

Comment: Это pdb в IDLE запускает. Это тоже debugger, но в IDLE есть свой встроенный debugger доступный из меню Debug.

Comment: Можно ставить breakpoint'ы с помощью правой кнопки мышы, но у меня с асинхронными вызовами это не работает.

Comment: Проверил, можно работать без pdb - нужно сначала открыть окно debugger, разрешить инкспектировать "globals", и в коде модуля (должен быть сохранен) поставить через контекстное меню breakpoint. 
Далее можно выполнять код пошагово с помощью "step". "Go" - отрабатывает до следующего breakpoint.